# What is the best library in python to deal with excel files?

Tags: java, python, excel, apache-poi, openpyxl

I have big excel with lot of sheets and formulas interlinked within the sheets. I need to populate input in one sheet using the code and recalculate all the formulas to get my output from another sheet.

I am able to do this with apache POI using Java but it is too slow in formula recalculation. Looking for libraries in Python to do the same.

Comment: Take a look at OpenPyXL [https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/]

Comment: why do you need a Java tag on this question, if it's not at all about Java?

Answer (score 10):

The best ones as I worked with them are `XlsxWriter` and `xlwings`.
Both work smoothly and efficiently and are compatible with Python and Excel.

`Xlwings` has two versions: `Free` and `Pro (paid version)`. The **free** version can do almost anything you need to work with an Excel file. With the paid version, you can get more functionality and support, which developers (not regular users) do not usually need.

On the other hand, `XlsxWriter` is also an excellent choice. Its user community has been growing fast recently. It supports everything you need to work with an Excel file.

Both can be installed simply with `pip` and `conda`.

The other libraries, such as `xlrd` and `xlwt`, were designed in the past to handle the old version (**.xls**) files. They are not comparable with the other two libraries that I mentioned.

`OpenPyXl` is also a decent library that can handle most of your needs. However, it needs more support to grow. In my opinion, it is not yet mature.

The `Pandas` and `pyexcel` libraries are also suitable for reading and writing data to an Excel file. I prefer **Pandas** because it is a mature and fast library that can handle big data. **pyexcel** is a wrapper API that is less capable than *Pandas* and more complicated to work with.

`PyXLL` is a professional library that can handle almost everything a user wants in Excel with Python. One of the famous companies working on Python distributions, `Enthought`, supports the library. Unfortunately, there is no free or community version of it, and you can only choose a 30-day trial of the pro version. After that, you must pay at least $29 per month. It is powerful, but it is an expensive choice for a single developer.

Of course, there are more `Libraries`, `Wrapers` and `APIs` for handling Excel files, but I mentioned the most mature and popular libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Below are a few libraries which do that. Recommend going through them as per your requirements.

1. [`Pycel`](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel)
2. [`formulas`](https://pypi.org/project/formulas/)
3. [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)
4. [`xlwt`](https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/)
5. [`Openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

They all blend with excel really well. You can try these out.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add some more libraries to Mayanks

1. matplotlib for data visualisation
2. Numpy
3. OpenpyXl
4. xlrd
5. xlwt
6. XlsxWriter

You can go through each and choose what suits best to your needs